# How do I check to see if a string is within an array in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I am a PHP developer and not a Visual Basic person.

I have an array:

```
Dim ShippingMethod() As String = {"Standard Shipping", "Ground EST"}
Dim Shipping as String = "Ground EST"
```

How do I do an `if` statement that will check if the string `Shipping` is in the `ShippingMethod()` array?

Comment: Related, but ***not*** duplicate (for a `List(Of String)`): *[Check if a list of strings contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732563)*

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__):

```
If ShippingMethod.Contains(Shipping) Then
    'Go
End If
```

That implies case-sensitivity. If you want case insensitive:

```
If ShippingMethod.Contains(Shipping, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    'Go
End If
```

Answer (score 12):

I get the error `'Contains' is not a member of 'String()'` if I try the above answer.

Instead I used [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

```
Dim index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(ShippingMethod, Shipping)
If index < 0 Then
    ' not found
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
Dim things As String() = {"a", "b", "c"}
If things.Contains("a") Then
    ' do things
Else
    ' don't do things
End If
```